# sub-string in a enabledelayedexpansion batch file

Tags: batch-file

*Edit 27-05-2018:
I have a variable called "Var01" that as the string "String01" assigned to it.
I think I wanted to create a substring from the variable's name "Var01" eg something like "ar01".
Upon review, I don't think is actually be possible because "Var01" is a variable and not a string (I may be wrong). If it is possible, how can I extract a substring from the variable "Var01", not a substring of the string assigned to "Var01".*

What I was originally trying to do was return a substring of the variable called "Var01"

This is some code I am playing around with in BATCH files. I am unable to get the following in bold working.

**call echo VariableName: %~1 VariableName's substring: %%~1:~1,4%%**

If it was working correctly, it should return "ar01" and then "ar02"
I want to be able to grab the variable's name and create a substring from it.

```
@cls
@echo off
echo Name of this batchfile: %~n0
echo/
goto :MainFunction

:Func01
echo/
echo Running Func01
call echo VariableName: %~1 VariableValue: %%%~1%%
call echo VariableName: %~1 VariableName's substring: %%~1:~1,4%%
call echo VariableValue: %%%~1%% VariableValue's substring: %%%~1:~1,1%%
echo/
set /P "%~1=Set new value for Variable %~1: "
goto :EOF

:MainFunction
echo This is the main function!
set "Var01=string01"
set "Var02=string02"
echo Var01 is equal to %Var01% and a substring is %Var01:~1,1%
echo Var02 is equal to %Var02% and a substring is %Var02:~1,1%
call :Func01 Var01
call :Func01 Var02
echo/
echo Var01 is now equal to %Var01%
echo Var02 is now equal to %Var02%
pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Please clue us in as to what you are expecting to achieve.

Comment: sustring substituation does not work with parameter variables `%1` or `for` variables `%%a`.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  You should study the output from `help set`.  Sub-string manipulation works well with the set command.

Comment: The 'call echo VariableName:  %~1 VariableName's substring: %%~1:~1,1%%' this part of the code that is not working. @Magoo, I am just trying to learn more about batch.

Comment: You have certain expectations that your code should achieve. It obviously isn't doing what you expect it to do, otherise you wouldn't have posted the question. Unfortunately, we have no idea of what you *expect* the code to do, so we're guessing if we attempt to fix it. If you tell us what you expect the code to do, and what results you are actually achieving, with actual examples, we are more able to assist.

Comment: My bad, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: 27-05-2018 have edited the question.